# SQL error: Not Unique table/alias

Tags: sql

I'm getting

```
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'default_event_rel_type'
```

my query is:

```
SELECT `default_users`.`username` as user,
       `default_event_rel_type`.`title` as title
  FROM (`default_event_rel`, `default_event_rel_type`)
  JOIN `default_users` ON `default_event_rel`.`uid` = `default_users`.`id`
  JOIN `default_event_rel_type` ON `default_event_rel_type`.`id` = `default_event_rel`.`eid`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have incorrect syntax in your `FROM` clause. You are calling `default_event_rel_type` twice. And you only need to call it once in your `JOIN`. You don't need to have it in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT `default_users`.`username` as user, `default_event_rel_type`.`title` as title 
FROM `default_event_rel`
JOIN `default_users` 
    ON `default_event_rel`.`uid` = `default_users`.`id` 
JOIN `default_event_rel_type` 
    ON `default_event_rel_type`.`id` = `default_event_rel`.`eid`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the table in the From statement

FROM (`default_event_rel`, `default_event_rel_type`)

and then join to it later in the query.